# Eigenfunctions and Eigenvalues of a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

For a math project on Schroedinger's equation I and a partner are working on we need to find eigenfunctions and eigenvalues that satisfy $L\phi_n = \lambda_n\phi_n$, where $L$ is defined as $L\psi = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[D \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}]$ and D is a negative constant and $\phi = 0$ at $x = L$ and $x = 0$.

My partner and I have been working on this part for the past few days and haven't been able to come up with an answer we're happy with.  Our teacher said we should end up with something of the form $\phi_n = A_ni\sin{\sqrt{\lambda}x}+B_n\cos{\sqrt{\lambda}x}$.  We're unsure how to get there from the original equation though.

Starting from the definition, we get $-D\frac{\partial^2\phi_n}{\partial x^2} = \lambda_n\phi_n$.  Solving for $\lambda$ gives $-D\frac{\frac{\partial^2\phi_n}{\partial x^2}}{\phi} = \lambda_n$.  Since $\frac{\partial^2\phi_n}{\partial x^2}$ should equal $\phi$, that makes it seem like $\lambda = i\sqrt{D}$ and $\phi = e^{i\sqrt{D}x}$.  We're unclear how the exponential transitions into $\sin$ and $\cos$ and where the constants $A_n$ and $B_n$ come from or if we've taken the correct approach so far.

Comment: Is $\psi$ dependent on time? And $$\phi = A \exp \bigg( +i \sqrt{ \frac{\lambda}{D}} x \bigg) + B \exp \bigg( -i \sqrt{ \frac{\lambda}{D}} x \bigg)$$ where $A, B$ are constants. If you differentiate the $\phi$ you derived, it doesn't satisfy $L \phi = \lambda \phi$. The exponentials becomes sines and cosines through [Eulers formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: In that instance, $\psi$ is just a dummy variable that is only a function of x.  Thanks for that article, it was really helpful.

Comment: If you are still stuck, just comment below and I'll make a post that goes through it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Differential equations of the form $y''(x)+\lambda y(x)=0$ have solutions $e^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x}$, $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$, and $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$. As for a derivation of these, one can use a power series expansion or other traditional method. Unfortunately, there is no closed form solution for second order differential equations if you don't already know one solution (that is, if I tell you one solution, it isn't hard to find a second, but finding the first one is typically a matter of guesswork).

Since differentiation is a linear operation, that is, since $\frac{d}{dx} cf(x)=c(\frac{d}{dx} f(x))$ with $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)+g(x)=\frac{d}{dx} f(x) +\frac{d}{dx} g(x)$, we know that we can take any linear combination of the solutions stated in the beginning and that these linear combinations will all still satisfy our differential equation. This is very much related to the reason that we can get from $e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ being a solution to our trig function solutions: since the function is composed of independent imaginary arguments and real arguments, we know that both arguments must be solutions on their own since no cancellation can occur. Hope that helps!